# segmentation fault on reading certain files, seems to be unrelated to filesize

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

thanks for taking the time to help me out with this.

So I'm making a terminal-based file manager in C++, and I added a functionality to read files.
This works, except that for certain files, it consistently throws a segfault.
This always happens consistently to the same files, but I haven't found a pattern yet.
My friend suggested it might have been a trailing newline, but I tried removing them and they still triggered a segfault.
I debugged, and found out which line is causing it, and used valgrind to create a memory log, both of which will be included.

What I know:

- As previously mentioned, it doesn't seem to be because of trailing newlines
- File size doesn't seem to matter, as this last occurred on a 2 byte file. But also on bigger files.

[Valgrind output](https://gist.github.com/JohnyTheCarrot/bbf95601b495e6afd8b1e18d4d615b5a)

If you need anything else, feel free to ask! :)

```cpp
void viewFile()
{
    clear();
    attron(A_STANDOUT);
    mvaddstr(0, 0, std::string(COLS, ' ').c_str());
    mvaddstr(0, 0, "File Contents:");
    attroff(A_STANDOUT);
    std::string filePath = getSelectedFile().c_str();
    std::ifstream file(filePath); // this line throws a segfault on some files
    std::string line;
    int index = fileViewStart;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        lineNumber++;
        if (index - fileViewScrollOffset >= fileViewStart && index - fileViewScrollOffset < fileViewEnd)
            mvaddstr(index - fileViewScrollOffset, 0, (std::to_string(lineNumber) + std::string(fileViewMarginLeft, ' ') + line).c_str());
        index++;
    }
    mvaddstr(LINES - 1, 0, "Continue [ENTER]");
    isShowingOutput = true;
    isViewingFile = true;
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: What does `getSelectedFile()` return? It looks like a `std::string` so `.c_str()` doesn't seem necessary. Btw, running `valgrind` on `ncurses` programs is horrible. Can you make a [mcve] without any of the `ncurses` stuff where you just try to open the files that makes it segfault?

Comment: Please read the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you know what `filePath` contains, then hard-code it. And if you think the error occurs when you try to open the `ifstream`, then remove the lines after that point and verify that the error still occurs.

Comment: Have you investigated the Valgrind errors? They very clearly point to lines 522 and 525 of your main.cpp. Where are those lines?

Comment: Hmm, is `getSelectedFile()` returning a `std::filesystem::path`? If so, why not do: `auto filePath =  getSelectedFile();`?

Comment: Just because your program crashes on one of the lines above, doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in your program which is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Since it's faulting on the `ifstream` constructor and the only input you have into that is the file name, *that's* where I'd be looking first. In other words, print out `filePath` before you attempt to use it.

And I don't necessarily mean just `std::cout << filePath << '\n'` (though that *may* be enough to see the problem). You may need to output the length and every single byte in case some weirdness has escaped into it :-)

---

Another possibility, seeing that your `valgrind` output has a lot of warnings, is that you are using possibly invalid values from memory, which can certainly cause issues even in the presence of otherwise well-written code:

- `Invalid read of size 1. Address 0x4f990e2 is 210 bytes inside a block of size 212 free'd.`
- `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s).`
- `Use of uninitialised value of size 8.`
- `Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x48B2B30.`

You probably want to dive deeper in to those issues as well.